# Segmentation Fault when creating a new process with fork in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, process, segmentation-fault

I am currently creating a shell program, for some reason, I am getting a segmentation fault when I'm running this code. Just a slight FYI, I'm aware that you would normally have `wait(NULL)` where I have put the `sleep(1)`'s but I am having these processes executed in the background, so if you could recommend fixes so that the code; A) doesn't segmentation fault, and B) executes the process in the background. Many thanks in advance for any tips and advice given. Also, for some further clarifications, the parsing process works, as in the full program, the shell program works for standard process execution, as well as, piped, and stdin and stdout altered processes. That said, here's the code with (sort of) minimal main program:

```
int main(void) {

  Command cmd;
  char **cmds;

  while (!done) {

    char *line;
    line = readline("> ");

    if (!line) {
      /* Encountered EOF at top level */
      done = 1;
    } else {
      /*
       * Remove leading and trailing whitespace from the line
       * Then, if there is anything left, add it to the history list
       * and execute it.
       */
      stripwhite(line);

      if(*line) {
        add_history(line);
        /* execute it */
        n = parse(line, &cmd);
        PrintCommand(n, &cmd);
        cmds = getCmds(cmd.pgm);
        execBgCmd(line, cmds, pipedCmds, cmd);
      }
    }

    if(line) {
      free(line);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int execBgCmd(char **cmds, Command cmd) {

  pid_t pid1, pid2;
  int status;

  pid1 = fork();
  if (pid1 < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failure");
    return 1;
  } else if (pid1 == 0) {
    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failure");
    } else if (pid2 == 0) {
      if (cmd.rstdin != NULL) {
        int fd0 = open(cmd.rstdin, O_RDONLY);
        dup2(fd0, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd0);
      }
      if (cmd.rstdout != NULL) {
        int fd1 = open(cmd.rstdout , O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0644) ;
        dup2(fd1, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd1);
      }
      if (execvp(cmds[0], cmds) < 0) { 
        printf("\nCould not execute command, try again.\n"); 
      } 
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a small main to allow the problem to be repeated. Without knowing the values of cmds, and cmd, hard to provide any feedback.

Comment: There is no need to sleep, if you want the process to run in the background.

Comment: @dash-o done... I hope.

Comment: What should be typed (to the readline) to replicate the problem ?

Comment: impossible to reproduce problem, as many support functions are not included (`stripwhite`, etc.). Consider running with a debugger, which will tell you where the segfault is. Impossible to answer your question given missing code

Comment: @dash-o okay, good suggestion, thank you

Comment: Not to mention that you call `execBgCmd(line, cmds, pipedCmds, cmd);` (4 parameters), but define the function as `execBgCmd(char **cmds, Command cmd)` taking only 2 arguments. Does the code even compile without warnings  ?

Comment: @dash-o that was my bad in altering it to be a minimal reproduction, I normally have it going to an execution decider, for instance, if it's an input containing a pipe it goes somewhere else to if it doesn't etc.